# Change user feed order so that items are strictly chronological

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange, recent-activity, feed

The [RSS user activity feed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/user/192221) orders answers before comments. This seems odd - could we instead order events chronologically (regardless of type) as per [the activity tab](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/192221/duncan-jones?tab=activity)?